# Mock new operator in c++ using GMOCK

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator, googletest, googlemock

Is there any way to **mock new operator or overloaded new operator** in C++ using GMOCK.
For eg:

```
ptr = new Base;
ret = ptr->call();
```

Here I need ptr should call mocked function but ptr is getting memory using new, so is there anything I can do to mock new here.

Comment: _'but ptr is getting memory using new'_ I think I don't get your question. Is `Base` a mock class? Then `ptr->call();` should call the mocked function. Why do you want to mock `new()`. It won't be possible to provide a mock function for it, since it's not a class member function.

Comment: @g-makulik even if I create mock class for Base for calling mocked function of it we need address of mock object (say mockBase) in ptr. As you can see ptr is getting memory from heap, I have to malloc new so that I can store address of mockBase in ptr.
I have a class Memory in that I have #defined MyNew new and other overloaded versions of new

Comment: Maybe it's a problem of your design then. You shouldn't create these instances directly, but either pass them where they're needed or even better having a factory class to create them (which could be easily mocked in turn). Fact is: You can't mock `new()`!

Answer (score 1):

There are those times when you have to do stupid stuff and get over with.

To mock operator `new`, you can overload it: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/new/operator_new

You can mock free functions such as the `new` implementation by creating a separate class for free functions, and constructed in the global scope.

There is a problem with simply mocking the `new` operator however, as the Google Test library also uses it. To make it work for all instances of `new`, make it dynamically change its behavior with a variable. Change this variable within the test to enable mocking.

To put it all together, it should look like this:

```
class MockFunctions
{
public:
    MOCK_CONST_METHOD1( newAllocate, void*( size_t ) );

    bool mockAllocation = false;
} mockFunctions;

void* operator new[]( size_t count )
{
    if ( mockFunctions.mockAllocation )
        return mockFunctions.newAllocate( count );

    else
        return std::malloc(count);
}
```

If you are able to modify the source code being tested, try to use STL containers such as array and vector to make life 100 times easier.